# Web bluetooth, get paired devices list

Tags: javascript, web, bluetooth, web-bluetooth

I use web bluetooth in my project, I connect to the device using this code

```
async function requestDevice() {
    bluetoothDevice = await navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
        // filters: [ { name: 'Device test' } ],
        acceptAllDevices: true,
        optionalServices: [
            'battery_service',
            '03b80e5a-ede8-4b33-a751-6ce34ec4c700'
        ]
    });

    bluetoothDevice.addEventListener('gattserverdisconnected', onDisconnected);       
}
```

Always to connect, I call the dialog box and there I select the device I need. Can I programmatically get a list of already connected devices? In order not to invoke a dialog box each time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is not currently a way to get a list of Bluetooth devices in Chrome. However, I am working on implementing a `getDevices()` method for Bluetooth. Please follow the status in [Chrome Platform Status](https://chromestatus.com/feature/4797798639730688)

**6/22/20 Edit:**

I recently implemented a new permissions backend as well as two APIs that will enable previously permitted Bluetooth devices to be used.

The new permissions backend is implemented behind the chrome://flags/#enable-web-bluetooth-new-permissions-backend. The new backend will persist device permissions granted through [`requestDevice()`](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#dom-bluetooth-requestdevice) until the permission is reset in Site Settings or the Page Info dialog box.

The [`getDevices()`](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#dom-bluetooth-getdevices) and [`watchAdvertisements()`](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#dom-bluetoothdevice-watchadvertisements) are implemented behind the chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features flag for Chrome 85.0.4165.0 or greater. The recommended use of these APIs is to use `getDevices()` to retrieve an array of permitted BluetoothDevices and then calling `watchAdvertisements()` on these devices to start a scan. When advertisement packets are detected from the devices, the [`advertisementreceived`](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#eventdef-bluetoothdevice-advertisementreceived) Event will be fired on the device that it corresponds to. At this point, the Bluetooth device is in range and can be connected to.

Please give this new feature a try, and file any bugs at https://crbug.com using the Blink>Bluetooth component.